# Putting a struct of int types to ostream in Big Endian to convert to char *

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, network-programming, deserialization

I have a message to be exchanged over `UDP` sockets which I implemented using `struct` of `uintN_t` in `stdint.h`.

It is required that any data passed to UDP sockets be in `Big Endian`, and of course, of type `char *` or `const char *`.

The systems I am running this program are Little Endian based.

I am not familiar with serialization, and based on answers on SO, I tried `put()`ting the data in reverse order to `ostringstream` to do this. (see the code below for detail)

```
void put_u16_as_big(ostringstream& oss, uint16_t data) {
    oss.write((const char *)&data, sizeof(data));
    if (is_big_endian()) {
        oss.write((const char *)&data, sizeof(data));
    }
    else {
        const char * ptr = (const char *)&data;
        unsigned int s = sizeof(data);
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < s; ++i) {
            oss.put(ptr[s-1-i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I put all data in struct to an instance of `ostringstream` and called `str()` method, the size of the data is not what it should be(smaller than 8bytes * 2 + 8bytes * 3 * the number of all servers, as in the table above), and `data()` method from that string, it shrinks even further(to 8).

Finally, when it is received on the other side, the size is 1.

How can I serialize my struct into a `char *` and send and receive without losing any data?

The `struct` contains fields with `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` types, and a vector (for a list of servers) of another struct which also contains `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `int16_t`.

Please help me. I've been struggling to solve this for days but had no luck..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the socket API `htons()` (host to network short) and `htonl()` (host to network long) functions to convert multi-byte integers from the local machine's native endian into network byte order (big-endian).  On big-endian system, the operation is a no-op.  On little-endian systems, the bytes are swapped.  You can use `ntohs()` (network to host short) and `ntohl()` (network to host long) to convert multi-byte integers from network byte order into the local machine's native endian.

Note that some functions, like `inet_addr()`, `gethostbyname()` and `getaddrinfo()` report IPv4 addresses that are already in network byte order, so don't use `htonl()` and `ntohl()` on those values, use them as-is.

Then, define a byte-aligned `struct` to hold your message data, and then pass it **as-is** to `sendto()`, *DO NOT* convert it to an `ostringstream`.  Do not be confused by the fact that `sendto()` expects a `char*`, that is just for historic reasons. It actually expects raw bytes, not a string.

Try this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // or your compiler's equivalent

struct sMsgHeader
{
    // General Message header fields here...
};

// ...

struct sRouteUpdateServer
{
    uint32_t serverIP;
    uint16_t serverPort;
    uint16_t reserved;
    uint16_t serverID;
    uint16_t cost;
};

struct sRouteUpdateMsg
{
    sMsgHeader header;
    uint16_t numUpdateFields;
    uint16_t serverPort;
    uint32_t serverIP;
    sRouteUpdateServer servers[some max value here];
};

#pragma pack(pop) // or your compiler's equivalent
```

```
sRouteUpdateMsg msg;
// fill msg.header as needed...

msg.numUpdateFields = htons(...);
msg.serverPort = htons(...);
msg.serverIP = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfServers; ++i)
{
    msg.servers[i].serverIP = ...;
    msg.servers[i].serverPort = htons(...);
    msg.servers[i].reserved = 0;
    msg.servers[i].serverID = htons(...);
    msg.servers[i].cost = htons(...);
}

//...

sendto(..., (char*)&msg, sizeof(sMsgHeader)+8+(sizeof(sRouteUpdateServer)*numberOfServers), ...);
```

Or, if your compiler supports `offsetof()` (or you write your own):

```
sendto(..., (char*)&msg, offsetof(sRouteUpdateMsg, servers)+(sizeof(sRouteUpdateServer)*numberOfServers), ...);
```

Do the reverse on the receiving side.  Use `recvfrom()` to receive the message data, then call `ntoh...()` to convert the message's multi-byte integers as needed, before then processing the message.

Comment: Thank you, but could you show me some sample code? Please... I've read htons htonl and serialization sections in Beej's guide but couldn't successfully do the job... and that was why I used ostringstream and even that failed...

Comment: `ostringstream` is the completely wrong approach, don't even look at it for this. This is not a serialization issue, it is a byte endian issue, and that is exactly what `hton...()` and `ntoh...()` deal with.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to apply the code, but there is one concern. The number of servers(`struct server` contains serverIP1, serverPort1, reserved1, serverID1, cost1) is determined at compile time(from a text file) and I defined a `vector<struct server>` inside the definition of `sRouteUpdateMsg`. I don't think this would work because then I am sending a pointer to another host. A pointer array would give the same result. How can I fix this? If I have a fixed-size array with some large number(let's say struct server servers[20]) and add 5 servers to it and `htons/htonl()` each element

Comment: in the `struct server`, will I be fine?

Comment: No, you cannot put a `vector` into the struct that you send. A fixed length array will work, though. Just make sure you specify the correct message size when you call `sendto()`, based on the number of servers eg `sizeof(header)+6+(sizeof(server)*numberOfServers)`, don't use `sizeof(msg)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a few more question. What is that 6 for in calculating the size? And will I be fine with the empty spots in the array(for example, 5 servers in an array of 20 servers)?

Comment: The 6 is the size of the first 3 fields - `Number of update fields`, `Server port`, and `Server IP` - before the per-server fields. And yes, you can leave the unused fields empty as long as you take into account that they are not being used.

Comment: Shouldn't the size of the 3 fields `2bytes + 2bytes + 4bytes = 8 bytes` and `= sizeof(sRouteUpdateMsg)` so `the size of the message = sizeof(sRouteUpdateMsg) + (sizeof(server)*numberOfServers)`?

Comment: Please disregard what I've just said if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it should be 8, not 6, sorry.  But no, the size of the message you pass to `sendto()` would not be the full `sizeof(sRouteUpdateMsg)` unless you are sending as many servers as `sRouteUpdateMsg` can physically hold max. The `servers` array is part of `sRouteUpdateMsg` and would be counted in full by `sizeof(sRouteUpdateMsg)`. That is why you have to count the content of `sRouteUpdateMsg` **up to but not including** the `servers` array, and then separately count the number of items in the `servers` array that are actually being sent.

Comment: The only reason I keep mentioning a separate header is because your diagram states: "The message format **for the data part** is", which implies that there is a **message header** that is described separate from the diagram you provided.